# How to remove BOM character from file's name?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to open particular files, but I receive:

```
FileNotFoundError: No such file: C:\\Users\\Jonis\\Desktop\\New folder\\vardai tikri\\becach_besmile_vardai_failas_\ufeff3.txt
```

I found out that this is BOM character at the end of the files name which appears as `/ufeff3`. This is what I tried:

1. `encoding = 'utf-8-sig'` did not work
2. tried to modify file's name: `filename[:-11]+"3.txt"`, but without any luck

Code:

```
filename = "C:\\Users\\Jonis\\Desktop\\New folder\\vardai tikri\\becach_besmile_vardai_failas_3.txt"
with open(filename, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line)
```

How can I remove BOM extension from files name?

Comment: Please post code that runs and reproduces the error when you run it.

Comment: Added real file name, but rest of the code is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking some time I found a solution which works. 
I simply replace "\ufeff" with empty string ""

```
filename = "C:\\Users\\Jonis\\Desktop\\New folder\\vardai tikri\\becach_besmile_vardai_failas_3.txt"

filename = filename.replace("\ufeff", "")
with open(filename, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line)
```